# How to get fixed string from string with different length in excel

Tags: excel, string

I have a problem in Excel. Please see my file `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vz4zlygKXCv0C13cxc0ypC5psvn8t6-Wbf6Qx_L18kw`

I have a 2 columns: **Transaction Description** and **ID Student**.

I need to extract ID Student from **Transaction Description** column (ID Student is code have 10 digits)

Comment: Use MID in combination with FIND as a starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the formula in column B ,

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("Hoc phi",A1)-11,10),RIGHT(A1,10))
```

and drag down.

Comment: Thanks @Gowtham Shiva for your formula, but some case I can't get exactly ID Student (Please see again my link). Text color is red which I want to get it, background color is orange which wrong value. If in Transaction Description don't have any ID Student or ID Student less than 10 digits (example row 306) so ID Student is blank.

Comment: @DucPhuocLai Your data is quote random and there is no pattern at all. Unfortunately it cant be done in excel. For wrong values you have to do it manually

Comment: OK, I rethink about this problem as the same you. Thank you @Gowtham Shiva.